# Adding a standard page to a VF page

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, standard-objects, event

I want to add my standard page to my Vf page. I am trying to add some features to my Event page layout (added a VF page) but it is not visible while we create a event it only visible after the record get saved i need it on the time of creation.

For that i have created a VF page need to add all the features of the Event page to my page + additional features i need with it. can anybody guide me how to get it done.

Answer (score 1):

The VF page section in the page layout will not be visible in edit mode. You can try creating a VF page with all the fields as you had mentioned.

Try the AppExchange called "Layout Page" which is a free app that creates a VF page for the object & page layout you specify in the app. I have used this app and it is good.

The AppExchange URL is:
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wZkUEAU

Hope this solves your issue.